# Will this TV mount holds LG OLED C8 65"?

Tags: television, mount

I have 24inches stud and bought a LG OLED C8 65 inches.
Looking at this TV mount: [https://www.amazon.com.au/Bracket-Articulating-MD2380-24-Mounting-Dream/dp/B06XZ6S9VG/ref=pd_sbs_504_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XZ6S9VG)

It says it only supports up to 55" but it does support LG OLED C8 65" VESA size 300m x 200m. It also supports up to 45kg which should be fine cause C8 65" Net Weight without stand is only 21kg. LG OLED C8 specs: https://www.lg.com/au/support/products/documents/OLED%20C8%20Product%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf

I could get a bigger frame but I don't want the bigger frame to block the cable inputs on the backside since it looks quite wide and C8 has some cable input on the right of backside.

Bigger mount:
[https://www.amazon.com.au/Articulating-600x400mm-MD2298-Mounting-Dream/dp/B00UT3O46E/ref=sr_1_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UT3O46E)

C8 backside:
https://www.lg.com/uk/images/tvs/MD05933200/gallery/medium05.jpg

just wanna ask it should be fine to purchase to mount the C8 65" ?? Seems to tick all the boxes: [https://www.amazon.com.au/Bracket-Articulating-MD2380-24-Mounting-Dream/dp/B06XZ6S9VG/ref=pd_sbs_504_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XZ6S9VG)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the mount would work in that the TV wouldn't fall off the wall.  However you might not be happy with the length of the articulating arm.  If the arm is short, and the TV is wide, you won't be able to turn it left and right like you want to.